# Cache Access Denied. Authentication Required in requests module

Tags: python, python-3.x, caching, proxy

I am trying to make a basic web crawler. My internet is through proxy connection. So I used the solution given [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/). But still while running the code I am getting the error. 
   My code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.4
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import urllib.request as req
proxies = {
    "http": r"http://usr:pass@202.141.80.22:3128",
    "https": r"http://usr:pass@202.141.80.22:3128",
}

url = input("Ask user for something")

def santabanta(max_pages,url):
    page = 1
    while (page <= max_pages):      
        source_code = requests.get(url,proxies=proxies)
        plain_text  = source_code.text
        print (plain_text)  
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text,"lxml")
        for link in soup.findAll('a'):
            href = link.get('href')
            print(href)
        page = page + 1
santabanta(1,url)
```

But while running on terminal in ubuntu 14.04 I am getting the following error:

The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: http://www.santabanta.com/wallpapers/gauhar-khan/?

**Cache Access Denied.**

Sorry, you are not currently allowed to request http://www.santabanta.com/wallpapers/gauhar-khan/? from this cache until you have authenticated yourself.

The url posted by me is:http://www.santabanta.com/wallpapers/gauhar-khan/

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

1. open the url.
2. hit F12(chrome user)
3. now go to "network" in the menu below.
4. hit f5 to reload the page so that chrome records all the data received from server.
5. open any of the "received file" and go down to "request header"
6. pass all the header to request.get()

.[Here is an image to help you][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUEBE.png

Make the header as follows:

headers = { 'Accept':' */ * ',
            'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, sdch',
            'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.8',
            'Cache-Control':'max-age=0',
            'Connection':'keep-alive',
            'Proxy-Authorization':'Basic ZWRjZ3Vlc3Q6ZWRjZ3Vlc3Q=',
            'If-Modified-Since':'Fri, 13 Nov 2015 17:47:23 GMT',
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36'
            }

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to solve this problem.
What you can do is let your python script to use the proxy defined in your environment variable

Open terminal (CTRL + ALT + T)

`export http_proxy="http://usr:pass@proxy:port"`
`export https_proxy="https://usr:pass@proxy:port"`

and remove the proxy lines from your code 
Here is the changed code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.4
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import urllib.request as req
url = input("Ask user for something")

def santabanta(max_pages,url):
    page = 1
    while (page <= max_pages):      
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text  = source_code.text
        print (plain_text)  
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text,"lxml")
        for link in soup.findAll('a'):
            href = link.get('href')
            print(href)
        page = page + 1
santabanta(1,url)
```